# With Vue, how would I load different CSS files depending on some logic / data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

I'm trying to enable different theming options for my app that users can choose from.

I know that I could switch out a class on the `<body>` tag, but that would make the CSS far messier than just using two different .scss files with different variable values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of an elegant way to do this. If you're using single file components (SFCs) you can make use of [CSS modules](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html). From the `vue-loader` [documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#custom-inject-name) ..

> You can have more than one `<style>` tags in a single `*.vue`
>   component. To avoid injected styles to overwrite each other, you can
>   customize the name of the injected computed property by giving the
>   module attribute a value

```
<style module="a">
  /* identifiers injected as a */
</style>

<style module="b">
  /* identifiers injected as b */
</style>
```

So you might have a style tag for your common styling, and other style tags for theme specific styling. You can then decide which module/style-tag a class is picked from with a computed property that uses your logic to return the module's name.

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of any Vue-Specific approach, but in plain Javascript

```
const styleEl = document.createElement("style");
styleEl.innerHTML = "@import 'alternate.stylesheet.css'";
document.head.appendChild(this.styleEl);
```

(Obviously, you'd load the normal stylesheet by default, and the alternate stylesheet would need to completely override any rules in the normal stylesheet that were not desired.)